# String to Hash map to Gson conversion giving error com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object

Tags: java, json, gson

below is the function which is giving error

```
public Document<?> post(String v1, String app, CacheType objectType, String bucketName, String password,
        Document<?> customDoc)
                throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InternalException {
    String uri = null;
        uri = getURI() + "/" + v1 + "/postDoc/" + app + "/" + objectType.toString() + "/" + bucketName;
    String jsonRequest = populateRequest(objectType.toString(), customDoc);
    String jsonResponse = sendRestCallPost(uri, jsonRequest, password);
```

JsonResponse contains `{"code":500,"message":"com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 39 path $.firstKey.content"}`

Below is the populateRequest function

```
public static String populateRequest(String objectType, Document<?> response) {
    String _CONTENT = "content";
    String _EXPIRY = "expiry";
    HashMap<String, Object> jsonObj = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    if(objectType.equals("STRING")){
        jsonObj = (HashMap<String, Object>) populateToString(response);
    }
    else{
        map.put(_CONTENT, response.content());
        map.put(_EXPIRY, response.expiry());
        jsonObj.put(response.id(), map);
    }
    String gson = jsonObj.toString();
    return gson;
}

public static HashMap<?,?> populateToString(Document<?> response){

    HashMap<String, Object> jsonObj = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    String _CONTENT = "content";
    String _EXPIRY = "expiry";
    String id = response.id().toString().trim();
    String content = (String) response.content().toString().trim();
    map.put(_CONTENT, content);
    map.put(_EXPIRY, response.expiry());
    jsonObj.put(id, map);
    return jsonObj;
}
```

and the variable response contains  `JsonStringDocument{id='firstKey', cas=0, expiry=4000, content=json doc with first key}`  when populateRequest function is called

**EDIT** This is the Junit which test my code

```
public void testRemoveDoc() throws Exception {
    String id = "firstKey";
    couchCacheBucket = new CouchCacheBucket(instance, bucketName, password, applicationName, retry, host, port,
            useRest);
    // Data Preparation Step - Getting a document
    JsonStringDocument str = null;
    try {
        str = (JsonStringDocument) couchCacheBucket.getDoc(id, CacheType.STRING_TYPE);

        if (str==null) {
            String body = "json doc with first key";
            JsonStringDocument jsonStr = JsonStringDocument.create(id, 4000, body);
            Document doc = couchCacheBucket.insertDoc(jsonStr, CacheType.STRING_TYPE);
```

**JsonObj** contains  `{firstKey={expiry=4000, content=json doc with first key}}`

and **Gson** contains  `{firstKey={expiry=4000, content=json doc with first key}}`

and **JsonRequest** contains  `{firstKey={expiry=4000, content=json doc with first key}}`

Comment: Can you post the `content=json doc with first key` as well? I have a feeling you're nesting JSONs incorrectly. Or that the content JSON is not valid itself.

Comment: I didnt exactly get you what do I have to post? Can you please explain?

Comment: What is "json doc with first key" in your example? Is it a string? A JSON? Is it literally "json doc with first key"? If so, shouldn't it be quoted?

Comment: It is a string. I have edited my post to show how I am using it .

Comment: Can you post the String jsonRequest that is being returned from `populateRequest()`? Because it looks like the error is generated by `sendRestCallPost()`. It seems to be a 500 server error thrown by the server receiving the jsonRequest.

Comment: would you please debug and post what structure of `String` actually returns `populateRequest()` Method ??

Comment: edited my post to show what populateRequest returns

Comment: Post the actual `String jsonRequest`. For example `String jsonRequest = populateRequest(objectType.toString(), customDoc); System.out.println(jsonRequest);     String jsonResponse = sendRestCallPost(uri, jsonRequest, password);` What does this line produce? `System.out.println(jsonRequest);`

Comment: edited my post again

Answer (score 3):

What i have see your error stack

```
 MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 39 path $.firstKey.content
```

It means some problem with your `String` Object that you sent to the `REST-Api`as a Parameter .

What you trying to do is Changed a `HashMap` object directly to `String` 
So, In your code

Method

`public static String populateRequest(String objectType, Document<?> response)`

returns a `String` object generate by using of a `HashMap`.

In each `key` and `value` is not contains **double quote** `"key":"value"` instead of this your `String` Object contains `key:value`.

So, this may raise an exception when parsing your `String` parameters as a `JSONObject` at `REST-API` business logic Code.

For example if you try this code

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("first", "value1");
map.put("second", "value1" );
System.out.println(map.toString());
```

It will print

```
{
first=value1,  //don't have "".
second=value2,
}
```

not as like this.

```
{
"first" : "value1",
"second" = "value2"   //contains "".
}
```

> **Solution** :- Please  add `gson-2.2.2.jar` to your library  [Jar Download Link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgson222jar.htm)

and try this code to change your `HashMap` as a `Json`.

```
HashMap<String, String> complexHashMapObject = new HashMap<>();
Gson gsone = new Gson();
JsonObject res = gsone.toJsonTree(complexHashMapObject).getAsJsonObject();
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly the problem btu how do i handle it?

Comment: `String gson = jsonObj.toJson();` instead of `String gson = jsonObj.toString();`

Comment: r u using any `JSON` Library ?

Comment: Yes I am using Gson and Json

Answer (score 0):

Please  add `gson-2.2.2.jar` to your library  [Jar Download Link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgson222jar.htm)

and try this code to change your `HashMap` as a `Json`.

```
HashMap<String, String> complexHashMapObject = new HashMap<>();
Gson gsone = new Gson();
JsonObject res = gsone.toJsonTree(complexHashMapObject).getAsJsonObject();
```

Comment: answer added. You should try this might work for you @Legendary_Hunter